# interface do they have to match the implemented classes?

Tags: java, interface

im designing an interface for elements eg. hydrogen

```
public interface Element
{
    public int getNumber();
    public double getMass();
    public String getElement();
    public void setNumber(int other);
    public void setMass(double mass);
    public void setElement(String species);
    public String toString();
}
```

other than these properties i also have different state for non metal eg. solid , gas, liquid

conductivity for metal elements. since they're different types of data i was thinking of adding

```
public String getState();
public void setState(String inState);
public double getConuctivity();
public void setConductivity(double inConductivity);
```

and only use State in the non metal class and conductivity in the other.

eg. nonmetal class

```
CLASSFIELDS
-number
-mass
-element
-state
```

is this a correct approach?

thanks for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't have `setNumber`, `setMass` etc methods on a class representing an element. These are values which should be set at construction time.

Comment: You should probably add those methods (state, conductivity) to a more specific subtype.

Comment: I don't see how this interface could have more than one implementation. Why do you design it as an interface rather than just a class? Are there Element implementations where setting the mass (for example) does something different than in other implementations?

Comment: @JBNizet Because OP wants non metal elements to have states and metals to have conductivity. OP, if you ask me, you should combine them into a single class and get rid of the interface. Metals are not restricted to one state under regular conditions(mercury is liquid in ordinary conditions). Additionally, non metals can have conductivity.

Comment: @Flaom then these should be subclasses of Element.

Comment: Yeah actually that's a better idea, so long as they both have all the same fields.